# How to align uilabel icon with text in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, uilabel

I have used the following code to add icon to my UILabel

```
        UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_comments.png"];

        UIImage *myIcon3 = [self imageWithImage:image3 scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
        NSTextAttachment *attachment3 = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
        attachment3.image = myIcon3;


        NSAttributedString *attachmentString3 = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment3];
        NSString *temp3 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", test.noComments];
        NSAttributedString *titleString3 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:temp3];

        NSMutableAttributedString *myString3 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];
        [myString3 appendAttributedString:attachmentString3];
        [myString3 appendAttributedString:titleString3];


        cell.noComments.attributedText = myString3;
```

the problem now that the text is not aligned vertically with the icon, can any one tell me what is the problem and how can I solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in iOS >= 7.0 for some `_label`

```
NSRange range = [myString3.string rangeOfString:titleString3.string];
CGFloat dy = (_label.frame.size.height - _label.font.pointSize) / 2;
[myString3 addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:dy] range:range];

_label.attributedText = myString3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually set the bounds of your attachment to compensate.

```
CGFloat offsetY = //However much you need to offset the image + is down - is up
attachment3.bounds = CGRectMake(0, offsetY, myIcon3.size.width, myIcon3.size.height);
```